# Scale-in issue in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am not sure if this is the case, but I think I have the following problem.

After scale in happens some requests gets 5XX response. I am not sure if 5XX appears because of scale in, but it appears so. And what I think happens is that after scale in rule was applied my app instance is shut down before some requests got appropriate response.

Could it be the case? In case yes, maybe somebody knows the solution?

I am using Azure.

Update: currently I am getting 502 Bad Gateway, but the strange thing is that App Service is not showing any failures

[image]

My guess it the failure happens in IIS and it does not even reach my app. Could it be the case?

Comment: It would be better if you added some of the error messages that occur :)

Comment: To troubleshoot this issue more efficiently, please add some error message or screenshot,

Comment: I have just updated the question. I hope this info will help you. In case not, please let me know

Comment: This is happening to me too. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520151/azure-app-service-restart-when-scaling-in