# Azure App Service restart when scaling-in

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have a scheduled scale-in at 5PM (from 2 to 1 instance) and I noticed almost 3 minutes of downtime when it happened. I checked the logs and it shows that the single instance that remained was restarted the same time that the 2nd was shut down.

Is this supposed to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not supposed to happen. The instances are all independent. Also, I test it on my side, I scale from 3 to 1, it just shut down the two instances, not restart the remained one.

The logs in the Kudu:

[image]

Comment: @LarryFlewwelling manual, but I think it seems not to be related. If you want, I can test it for you.

Comment: If you can check that would be great. also, where are those logs in kudo?

Comment: @LarryFlewwelling Go to Debug console -> CMD-> LogFiles -> kudu -> trace, the id like `494acb` is your instance id.

Comment: @LarryFlewwelling well, as I supposed, it is the same with manual, https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUVgV.png.

Comment: Awesome, I see the logs. Thank you for your help.

So what I am seeing is just the Shutdown_2s.xml file. But when I check my application logs, I see hangfire shutting down, and then a new app log file was created, and hangfire starting up. This happens when there is an app restart. 

I'm guessing my app restarted but it wasn't caused directly by azure scaling. I will have to keep watching and see if I can figure out what happened.

I wonder...is there a way to log app pool restarts?

Comment: @LarryFlewwelling I am not sure, maybe you could try the [Application Insight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview) for your app.